In Snowflake, when using between condition in on clause, inner join is much faster than left join - any ideas why?
Using snowflake, need to join with a between condition in my on clause, I would rather do a left join but inner join is much faster for some reason - any ideas why?
Below is an example query, even for this query inner join is 2x faster than left, for big datasets the difference in performance grows gradually, any explanations/workarounds would be much appreciated
WITH 
orders AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (1, '2024-11-01'),
        (2, '2024-11-05'),
        (3, '2024-11-10')
    ) AS o(order_id, order_date)
),
promotions AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('A', '2024-11-01', '2024-11-03'),
        ('B', '2024-11-04', '2024-11-06'),
        ('C', '2024-11-08', '2024-11-12')
    ) AS p(promo_id, start_date, end_date)
)

SELECT 
    o.order_id,
    o.order_date,
    p.promo_id,
    p.start_date,
    p.end_date
FROM 
    orders o
JOIN 
    promotions p
ON 
    o.order_date BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date;

 


Because inner joins return only records that match across both tables whereas outer joins return all records from one table

Basic rule of thumb for Snowflake performance is to try and write queries that prune as much as possible.  Left joins always have 1 table that isn't pruned.  This is magnified a bit based on the BETWEEN join type because that is pruned separately as a > and a < when Snowflake decides which micropartitions to retrieve.  I would highly recommend you take a look at ASOF JOIN (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/asof-join) in this case to see if that performs better.
